# How to group Arrays by Date in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a model which contains a `date` property.

I can group the dates by `Dictionary(grouping..`

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: orders.results, by: { $0.createdAt })
```

But the issue is when doing decoding I did this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

So my `Date` property accounts for time as well.

How should I go about grouping by just `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Calendar startOfDay`.

```
let cal = Calendar.current
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: orders.results, by: { cal.startOfDay(for: $0.createdAt) })
```

Answer (score 4):

I like grouping by day because by Date groups by time interval and this solution grouping by the day, month and year.

```
let groupDic = Dictionary(grouping: arr) { (pendingCamera) -> DateComponents in
    print("group arr: \(String(describing: pendingCamera.date))")
        
    let date = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .year, .month], from: (pendingCamera.date)!)
        
    return date
}
```